# I want to check the grade of the students marks , based on average

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

What's wrong with this code? I tried get marks using array and pass the array in to function parameters and calculate the average in that function.

```
const marks = [100,100,80];
var summ = 0;

function calculateGrade(){
    
    for(let i=0; i<=marks.length;i++){
       
        summ = summ+marks[i];
        var avg = (summ/marks.length);  
    }
    
    if(avg<=59){
        console.log('F');
    }
    else if(avg>=60 && avg<=69){
        console.log('D');
    }
    else if(avg>=70 && avg<=79){
        console.log('C');
    }
    else if(avg>=80 && avg<=89){
        console.log('B');
    }
    else if(avg>=90 && avg<=100){
        console.log('A');
    }
}

console.log(calculateGrade(marks));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just added an extra **=** in your for loop

```
i<=marks.length
```

instead of

```
i<marks.length
```

So while calculating the sum & average, a garbage value gets added up.

Answer (score 2):

```
const sum = marks.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close

```js
const marks = [100, 100, 80];


function calculateGrade(marks) {

  let summ = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    summ += marks[i];
  }
  const avg = summ / marks.length;
  let grade = '';
  if (avg < 59) {
    grade = 'F';
  } else if (avg <= 69) {
    grade = 'D';
  } else if (avg <= 79) {
    grade = 'C';
  } else if (avg <= 89) {
    grade = 'B';
  } else {
    grade = 'A';
  }
  return grade;
}

console.log(calculateGrade(marks));
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch, It's working now. but after print the grade, there is a 'undefined' in my console. As well as your correction code snippet. Do you know the reason? I think it's comes from the last line of my code "console.log(calculateGrade(marks));".

Comment: The reason it showed "undefined" is that the calculateGrade function wasn't returning a value

Comment: I changed it to return the grade, instead of calling console.log. That way, the console.log that calls the function will display the return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const marks = [100, 100, 80];
  var summ = 0;
   
  //issue one (Tmarks were missing )
  function calculateGrade(Tmarks) {
    // issues 2 ( <= should be < )
    for (let i = 0; i < Tmarks.length; i++) {
      summ += Tmarks[i];
    }
    var avg = summ / Tmarks.length;
    if (avg <= 59) {
      console.log("F");
    } else if (avg >= 60 && avg <= 69) {
      console.log("D");
    } else if (avg >= 70 && avg <= 79) {
      console.log("C");
    } else if (avg >= 80 && avg <= 89) {
      console.log("B");
    } else if (avg >= 90 && avg <= 100) {
      console.log("A");
    }
  }

  console.log(calculateGrade(marks));
```

> Following were the issues in your code
>
> 1. You were not getting the parameters in function definition
> 2. issues 2 ( <= should be < )

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of mistakes in your code.

**1.**

```
for(let i=0; i<=marks.length;i++)
```

**marks.length** is 3. Array index starting from 0.

const marks = [100,100,80];

```
index 0 is 100. 
index 1 is 100.
index 2 is 80.
```

When you add **i<=marks.length**, this is equals to **i<=3**.

**=** in here will run the loop extra circle and this will return **NaN** because there are only 3 elements in you array and array indexing is 0 based.

**2.**

```
for(let i=0; i<=marks.length;i++){
   
    summ = summ+marks[i];
    var avg = (summ/marks.length);  
}
```

**avg** is out of scope. you have defined **avg** inside the loop and trying to access it outside of the loop. Anything declared in the loop is scoped to that loop and are not available outside the loop.

**3.**

```
console.log(calculateGrade(marks));
```

Your `calculateGrade()` function is not accepting any parameters. So you can't pass any parameter into this function.

**4.**

```
console.log(calculateGrade(marks));
```

since `calculateGrade()` function is not returning any value, this will print nothing. So you don't need to call this inside a `console.log();`.

I have simplified your code as below.

```js
const marksArr = [100, 100, 80];
calculateGrade(marksArr);

function calculateGrade(marks) {
  console.log('calling calculateGrade(marks)...');
  var avg = (marksArr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0)) / marksArr.length;
  console.log('avg is', avg);

  if (avg <= 59) {
    console.log('Grade', 'F');
  } else if (avg >= 60 && avg <= 69) {
    console.log('Grade', 'D');
  } else if (avg >= 70 && avg <= 79) {
    console.log('Grade', 'C');
  } else if (avg >= 80 && avg <= 89) {
    console.log('Grade', 'B');
  } else if (avg >= 90 && avg <= 100) {
    console.log('Grade', 'A');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
` calculateGrade(){
                    let marks   = [100,100,80];
                    let summ    = 0;
                    let avg     = 0;
    
                    for(let i = 0; i < marks.length; i++){
                        summ    = summ+marks[i];
                        avg     = (summ/marks.length);
                    }
                    
                    if(avg<=59){
                        console.log('F');
                    }
                    else if(avg>=60 && avg<=69){
                        console.log('D');
                    }
                    else if(avg>=70 && avg<=79){
                        console.log('C');
                    }
                    else if(avg>=80 && avg<=89){
                        console.log('B');
                    }
                    else if(avg>=90 && avg<=100){
                        console.log('A');
                    }
                }`

> array start from 0
```